# Path parameter in URL for http outbound gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I hava xml that include this :

```
<channel id="myDataChannel"></channel>
<http:outbound-gateway 
    request-channel="myDataChannel"
    url="{url}/myApi/getData/{id}"
    expected-response-type="com.api.dto.Data"
    http-method="GET" 
    rest-template="myRestTemplate">
    <http:uri-variable name="url" expression="headers.url" />
</http:outbound-gateway>
```

and in java code like this :

```
    MessagingTemplate myTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();
    Message<?> getDataReply = null;
    Data dataDto = null;

    Message<?> requestMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestDto)
            .build();

    getDataReply = template.sendAndReceive(myDataChannel, requestMsg);
    return dataDto = (Data) getDataReply.getPayload();
```

**here is my question how to path id in URL with payload in java code and there is an additional tag should I add to XML in out-bound-gateway ?**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but you need something like

```
Message<?> requestMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestDto)
        .setHeader("url", ...)
        .setHeader("id", ...)
        .build();
```

and

```
<http:uri-variable name="id" expression="headers.id" />
```

Or, if the id is a property of the payload

```
Message<?> requestMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestDto)
        .setHeader("url", ...)
        .build();
```

and

```
<http:uri-variable name="id" expression="payload.id" />
```

Comment: i mean when i call api for example I have id from request and want send its value 
like this URL : **HTTP//localhost:8080/myApi/getData/2**

if  I apply your solution will it create it like URL in my comment ?

Comment: Yes it will you just have to tell the adapter where to find the `id`.